# C/C++ Macro for null safe pointer access

Tags: c++, c, pointers, null, macros

I want to write a C/C++ macro for null safe pointer access. I currently have this, which works well:

```
#define NULL_SAFE(p, e) if (p) p->e
NULL_SAFE(myPtr, myMethod(myArg));
```

But what I really want is to have something like this:

```
NULL_SAFE(
  myPtr, myMethod(myArg),
  myOtherPtr, myOtherMethod(myOtherArg),
  yetAnotherMyPtr, plsStopMethod(grArg),
  ...
);
```

which would expand to:

```
  if (myPtr) myPtr->myMethod(myArg);
  if (myOtherPtr) myOtherPtr->myOtherMethod(myOtherArg);
  if (yetAnotherMyPtr) yetAnotherMyPtr->plsStopMethod(grArg);
```

I can think of a whole bunch of these I might like to use, but they all operate on the same concept as this.

Is this possible? Does this already exist somewhere? Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably better to use a reference so none of this crazy idea is required in the first place

Comment: Take a look at this: http://saadahmad.ca/cc-preprocessor-metaprogramming-basic-pattern-matching-macros-and-conditionals/

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If using C++ you may want to use smart pointers.

Comment: Using macros to reinvent the language is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: Macros may seem like a great thing, but often they make code hard to read and maintain. So my advice is to not use a macro for this, use explicit code instead.

Comment: Better than a macro would be a function taking the pointer and something to execute on it: `nullSafe(myPtr, [&](auto& pointee) { pointee.myMethod(myArg); });`. At that point, though, you basically have an `optional` and a `map` function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I am actually using C++, but I do use C when working with embedded devices so I figured this would help with that too. I do actually use smart pointers, I use a lot of shared_ptrs and weak_ptrs to control ownership of pointers, but you still need to check to make sure they are not null before using them. And @EmeraldWeapon, many LISPers would disagree with you on that point, but I agree this would not be appropriate for production code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree that in the general case macros make code harder to read and maintain, but are you arguing that the code you provided is less readable and less error prone than the sample code chris provided? In my opinion it is not. I appreciate both of your suggestions, however. Also, I don't think the lambda would work for < c++11 or C.

Comment: I don't really understand how something so generic would be useful. Normally, when you do a null check, you have to *handle* the nullity condition somehow. Under what circumstances would you want to dereference only valid pointers, while simply ignoring invalid ones? And in those circumstances, wouldn't you be better off using a container like std::map?

Comment: @RoboCop87 I plead total ignorance on LISP, but Idioms that are customary and useful in one language might not be very good in others. This being said, we are all consenting adults... :)

Comment: Are you actually gaining something by silently skipping statements if a pointer is null? I prefer a nice crash, showing the bug the program has. (A different story would be a macro named IF_NOT_NULL)

Comment: @CodyGray The use case I am currently targeting is one where dependencies are injected into a subsystem based on some abstract assembler and those subsystems may or may not exist depending on which assembler created the object. This object dispatches events to the subsystems it has and does not care in the case that it doesnt exist.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, I messed up that reply to your comment and I can't edit it now. Should be the code chris provided vs the sample code I provided. My apologies!

Answer (score 6):

If the NULL check is part of an algorithm, then just type out the NULL check explicitly without any icky macros.

If the NULL check is a way of defensive programming, the correct way to do this is `assert(ptr);`. If the assert ever triggers, go fix the bug that caused it. Repeat until there are no bugs left, then remove the assert from the production-quality code.

Comment: Unless a null pointer is an acceptable state of the program. See my reply to CodyGray's comment. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

C++11:

```
inline void null_safe()
{
}

template <typename Ptr, typename Fn, typename... Args>
void null_safe(Ptr&& ptr, Fn&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    if (ptr)
        fn();
    // you could put "else" here                                                                                                            
    null_safe(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You can use any callable as the second argument, so:

```
int f2() {
    return printf("f2\n");
}

int f3() {
    return printf("f3\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i1 = 1;

    null_safe(
        &i1, f2
        );

    null_safe(
        NULL, f2,
        &i1, f3
        );
}
```

You can also use any predicate as the first argument.

Why it's NULL there and not nullptr is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I had to google that one. nullptr evaluates to a pointer type vs NULL evaluating to an integer, which is apparently needed for your template to work. Thanks for the exercise!

Comment: If going the template road, you might pass arguments to the functions ...

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get to this is by using c++11 variadic templates, and C99 variadic macros ... sorry if your platform does not allow it, regardless it was great fun coming up with the code!

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void stuff(T a)
{
    std::cout<< "stuff:" << a << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void other_stuff(T a)
{
    std::cout<< "other_stuff:" << a << std::endl;
}

template <typename Test, typename ToCall>
void tester(Test t, ToCall tc)
{
    if(t) tc();
}

template <typename Test, typename ToCall, typename... Others>
void tester(Test t, ToCall tc, Others... args)
{
    if(t) tc();
    tester(args...);
}

#define FUN_WRAP(a,b) std::bind(a<decltype(b)>, (b) )
#define NULL_SAFE(...) tester(__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    NULL_SAFE(1, FUN_WRAP(stuff, 1),
        0, FUN_WRAP(stuff, 2),
        1, FUN_WRAP(other_stuff, 3)
        );
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but do you even need the NULL_SAFE macro once you have the variadic templated function? Also I was looking for a macro so it was back portable for pre c++11 compilers and C, but this would be good if it turns out a pure macro solution isn't possible!

Comment: @RoboCop87: A pure macro solution is possible.  But it is too disgusting to contemplate seriously.

Comment: No, you don't really need the `NULL_SAFE` macro.

Comment: @JohnZwinck "too disgusting to contemplate seriously" makes me want to learn how to do it even more, if not just for the academic exercise!